# $.post being turned into GET

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, post, get, request

My jQuery $.post calls work ok in my environment. But on production, $.posts are mysteriously being turned into GETs, returning 404.

Dev call:
$.post('/Home/Destaques')
(call works ok)

Production call:
$.post('/Home/Destaques') produces 
GET /Home/Destaques/ 404 (Not Found)

There are differences between the response headers, namely:

Dev:
Server:Microsoft-IIS/7.0
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
X-AspNetMvc-Version:2.0

Production:
Server:Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-AspNet-Version:2.0.50727
(no AspNetMvc header)

Why would a POST become a GET?

Comment: I think it's because of the change in relative url.

Comment: if not understand false, Use Action Attribute. For Destaques is action, use [HttpPost]

Comment: @jSang I think the relative url is the same: /Home/Destaques?

Comment: @BeratBilgin That's in use already.

Comment: Have you checked the correct version of asp.net mvc is installed on the server and the iis virtual directory / site is running the right version of .net?

Comment: @WestDiscGolf I was not able to as I was locked to an admin panel, and a poor one at that. I solved the issue by moving my application around. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

Use `@Url.Action` while specifying the location. And this is the best example of the issue which occurs and the main reason for `Url.Action` was introduced in MVC.

**EDIT-**

Dude See what happens is that we use Url.Action or Url.Content for the same purpose coz the way it is deployed may not be into the root itself.

The Analogy could be mapped to - *When you are lost somewhere between the ways to reach a destination , and you ask someone the way to the destination he Answers {Right- Right - left - Right} and you are there. But this might not work if you are not on the same point and follow that way.*

So for the server it happens the same. When it was there on the sub site it wasnt able to find the way out since the depth levels were different and as you changed it it started working . So, AFAIK this is the case.

Read Url.Action documentation . An example is given : [Scott Guthrie's( MVC GURU) blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/12/03/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-2-url-routing.aspx)

Comment: +1 would have suggested (and have on many occassions) exactly this remedy

Comment: I think in this case the location is ok: the /Home/Destaques is there in both enviroments.

Comment: @PedroSobota - Is this happening with only this action or other actions do get resolved ?? While deploying did you add handler for handling MVC routing ?? Since your Local is IIS/7.0 and Production is - IIS 6.0 . There's a bit of modification to be done while deploying on IIS 6 , It doesn't natively support URL routing. A handler is to be added for that.

Comment: @bhuvin The hosting server is theoretically ready to serve MVC 2, so they say. The routing works, as I can navigate the site. Only the ajax POSTs don't work (all of them). They get turned into GETs.

Comment: @PedroSobota - See the response , It says Asp.NET 2.0 mapped. I think check http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/07/04/options-for-deploying-aspnet-mvc-to-iis-6/ out . I have used it that way to deploy it on my servers. But your issue seems to be pretty weird. I am getting my seniors to look at your problem . Let me see what they think ?

Comment: @PedroSobota - Also please check the version of .net mapped to the app pool of the application.

Comment: @bhuvin It's difficult to know because I was locked to an administration panel, I didn't have direct access to IIS. I was not able to see exactly what was configured, such as ASP.NET versions, even if it did say 3.5. I solved the problem moving my application from a subsite position to a main site. I still don't know why this solved it, but it's one of these things. I think ultimately the panel (of poor quality) was my problem. I thank you and the others for the help.

Comment: @PedroSobota - Just edited my answer to make the things clear.